# No viable '=' when using vector::erase

Tags: c++, vector, assignment-operator

I am having some trouble with figuring out why I cannot seem to get std::vector::erase work with a vector of my own class objects. The following code throws a **"No viable overloaded '='"** error, and cannot figure out why after some extensive searching overflow/tutorialspoint/...

my class definition 'MyClass.hpp':

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class node;
class graph{
public:
    graph();
    std::vector<node> nodeList;
};

class node{
public:
    node(std::string name) : name(name){};
    void operator=(node& rhs);
    std::string name;
    std::vector<node> adjacent;
};

void node::operator=(node& rhs){
    name = rhs.name;
    adjacent = rhs.adjacent;
}
```

and my main file:

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    node node1("root"), node2("leaf");
    node1.adjacent.push_back(node2);
    node2.adjacent.push_back(node1);
    node1.adjacent.erase(node1.adjacent.begin());
    graph myGraph;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's entirely possible your vector implementation doesn't have the new support for incomplete types (a node having a vector of nodes).

Comment: Your `operator=` is broken. The assignment operator must take a `const` reference as a parameter, and return a mutable reference, i.e. it should be `node &node::operator=(const node& rhs)`, and return `*this`.

Comment: Why are you even defining `operator=` yourself?  The compiler-generated one would have been better.  See the Rule of Zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector::erase` adds the requirement that the type `T` of the vector's elements must be [*move assignable*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable). This means in particular that an expression like `t = rv` must have a return type of `T &` (reference to `T`) and a value of `t` (so the returned reference must reference the assigned to object).

Your `Node::operator=` has return type `void`, thus violates above requirement. Further, the usual (and probably most reasonable) type signatures for copy / move assignment operators are as follows:

```
T & operator=(T &&); // move assignment
T & operator=(T); // copy assignment, pass by value
T & operator=(T const &); // copy assignment, pass by const reference
```

But, instead of fixing your operator, you should **discard it all together**! Your `Node` class does (should) **not** deal with ownership (the `std::vector` is doing this for you), thus per the [rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) you should not provide a custom copy or move assignment operators (nor a destructor).

Comment: According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment), OP's assignment operator is a copy assignment operator.

Comment: @chris I read up in the standard, and indeed, the only requirement on the type signature for a copy assignment operator is the single parameter of type `T`, `T &`, `T const &`, `T volatile &` or `T const volatile &`.

Comment: Agreed. Without additional logic to handle conversions, assignments must be of the same T.  There are, however,  built in solutions for edge cases in c++ collections, but they should not always be relied on.

Comment: @DanielJour thank you, the explanation is very helpful.